# Rails 4 how to make enrolment to a course for users (controller, view, model)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, devise

I am currently trying to build a simple learning app with rails and I am facing problems. When a user signs up to a course i try to make a viewed_course record for them so that I can display all the viewed_course on their profile page.

I can't figure out how to set my different controllers so that it creates the viewed_record when I am on the Course Controller /index.

How can I modify the course/index view so that it creates a new viewed record for the current signed in user.

I am using devise.

```
class Course
    has_many :lessons
end

class Lesson
  #fields: course_id
  belongs_to :course
end
class User
  has_many :viewed_lessons
  has_many :viewed_courses
end
class ViewedLesson
  #fields: user_id, lesson_id, completed(boolean)  
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :lesson
end
class ViewedCourse
  #fields: user_id, course_id, completed(boolean)  
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :course  
end
```

Thank you so much in advance for helping me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it, this is in courses controller show action (index action should be the list of all courses, show action should be viewing an individual course):

```
class CoursesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @courses = Course.all
  end

  def show
    @course = Course.find(params[:id])
    current_user.viewed_courses.create(course: @course)
  end  
end
```

One gotcha is that this would create a new viewed course every time they viewed the page, you would need some logic to only add each course once.

Perhaps something like this:

```
def show
  @course = Course.find(params[:id])
  current_user.viewed_courses.create(course: @course) unless ViewedCourse.exists?(user_id: current_user.id, course_id: @course.id)
end
```

Comment: A nicer syntax is something like `@viewed_course  = current_user.viewed_courses.find_by_course_id(@course.id) || current_user.viewed_courses.create(course: @course)`

Comment: Thank you guys for great answer. What about the index view? should I use a form with a button 'Enroll now'? How would it be? I ask a lot but thank you in advance!

Comment: I thought when someone views a course via the show action (so clicks a link from the index for a course e.g site.com/courses/1) they then view the course page with more course specific info on it and it adds to viewed courses? 

A button would need to go to a create action not a show action, and would remove the need for a show action all together.

Comment: Yeah exactly. when they click on the class they have access to more details and then can enrol.

Comment: I think you need to move the current_user.viewed_courses.create line into a new ViewedCourses controller 'create' action. However it would probably make more sense to rename the model to EnrolledCourse instead and change the code accordingly.

Comment: You're welcome, pleased you got it working! Please mark my answer as accepted it you're happy with it.